# How to statically serve a local web app via electron, without a proxy server or client changes

Tags: electron

I have an application built to run on the web. It has an `index.html` with something like `<script src="/index.js"></script>` and an `index.js` with something like `fetch('/api/foo')`. It's also a single page app, with slash based routing (e.g. the server loads `index.html` when you go to `example.com/help`, and the app logic handles loading a different view.)

I want to wrap this application in electron, with static files (`index.html`, `index.js`, etc.) served locally, APIs served externally, without bundling a local proxy server or making client changes. I also only want to use the core electron utilities.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Under the above constraints, with the additional constraint of using `protocol`/`WebRequest`, **it may be impossible**.

The two commonly suggested electron APIs are [protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) and [WebRequest](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request), and do seem to be the most appropriate for solving the issues below. Those APIs seem built for this exact situation, and seem like they would provide an easy integration.

Initial problems serving the app from a file `loadURL( ... 'index.html' ... )`:

1. `<script src="/index.js"></script>` will try to load `file://C:/index.js`, when you need it to load `file://C:/<FILE_PATH>/index.js`
2. Clicking the `<a href="/help">` link will try to load `file://C:/help`, when you need it to load `file://C:/<FILE_PATH>/index.js` (but in a way where the app thinks its at `/help` so that it does appropriate routing).
3. `fetch('/api/foo')` will try to load `file://C:/api/foo.js`, when you need it to load `https://example.com/api/foo`.

Note the following facts:

- `protocol.interceptZZZProtocol` can only route to protocol of type `ZZZ`.
- `protocol.interceptZZZProtocol` intercepts all requests of type `ZZZ` and cannot be filtered.
- Any requests intercepted by `protocol.interceptZZZProtocol` will not be handled by `protocol.interceptXXXProtocol` or `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`.

Each one of these can be individually solved, but don't work together.

1. Using either `protocol.interceptFileProtocol` or `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, you can alter the request path.
2. Using `protocol.interceptFileProtocol`, you can access the content of `file://C:/<FILE_PATH>/index.js` through `file://C:/help`. This can't be done through `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, because that will only redirect the location back to the root `index.html` view. Note that using `protocol.intercept***Protocol` will prevent those requests (and the protocol of those requests) from being captured in `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` or in other `protocol.intercept***Protocol`.
3. Using `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, you can redirect the file protocol to the http protocol. This can't be done through `protocol.interceptFileProtocol`, which only interprets requests as files. Note this could be done with `protocol.interceptHttpProtocol`, but you can't handle the same protocol of requests with both `interceptHttpProtocol` and `interceptFileProtocol` (necessary in (2)).

**Note that solutions (2) and (3) contradict themselves.**

Other approaches I tried:

- Using `interceptHttpProtocol` to 'host' the app at some dummy URL (e.g. `example.com`)

  - Problem: Similar issues to the above.
- Custom protocol to capture certain requests.

  - Problem: `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` can't handle it, `protocol.intercept***Protocol` can't route to it.

Note: It may be possible to solve this problem by using `interceptBufferProtocol`, which I think may capture both http and file protocols. But there's no examples online, and you would need to reimplement file/http request handling.

---

This write-up doesn't consider problems beyond the initial ones. There are likely other potential issues with this approach, including HTTPS, sockets, or trying to do RESTful methods against a file endpoint.

Given the above difficulties, it is likely better to consider alternatives:

1. The best choice would be to use a bundled proxy server.
2. A secondary choice might be to modify the client in an attempt to skirt the above constraints.